# Python - Multithreading with a max pool including tqdm progressbar

Tags: python, multithreading, tqdm

i'm using a Python script to retrieve data on network device through Ip
I'm having troubles to display a progressbar with concurrent.futures
I was using this piece of code previously and i can track the progress with it but i don't like using time.sleep(1) in it.

```
data = {}
for ip in tqdm(listOfIp):
  t = threading.Threads(target=MyFunc, args=(ip,data))
  threads.append(t)
  t.start()
  while threading.active_count() >= 50:
    time.sleep(1)
# waiting for threads to finish
for thread in threads: threads.join()
```

I was trying to implement something like this:

```
data = {}
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(MyFunc, ip, data) for ip in listOfIp]
    pbar = tqdm(total=len(futures))
    while futures:
        completed, _ = concurrent.futures.wait(futures, timeout=0.1)
        for future in completed:
            pbar.update(1)
        futures -= completed

    pbar.close()
```

But with this i can't see the progressbar untill all the process has been either lauched or completed (i guess)
Any idea of a better way to achieve the same result as the previous code but with a clean process?
Thanks !